# JMeter load test thread dump

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter for load testing and some of my threads just hang. I want to do a thread dump but none of the following work from my linux machine

First get JMeter process id using

```
jps -l
```

Then did

```
sudo -u <username> jstack <pid>
```

and get the following msg

15141: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
The -F option can be used when the target process is not responding

even

```
kill -3 15141
```

comes up with nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lot of googling and trial and error found the solution

To take thread dumps, start JMeter using command line.
Open terminal (A)

```
$ cd /media/9260C06E60C05A9D/Downloads/jakarta-jmeter-2.4/bin
$ ./jmeter > temp
```

In another terminal (B)
Get the process id of JMeter

```
$ jps -l
$ kill -QUIT 21735
```

Now check temp file for thread dump.

In order to use jstack make sure the user and group user are the same as the user running jstack